# Point sprites in particle system?

Tags: particles

I don't understand [this passage](https://books.google.com/books?id=7SKKAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=%22You%20can%20create%20quads%20around%20those%20central%20points%20to%20which%20you%20can%20map%20textures%22&source=bl&ots=TnowXJGDzJ&sig=pJxSauoXZdWU3ZdQKMHOQru457s&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6JHgVKSpCcOtogSX5YGoCw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22You%20can%20create%20quads%20around%20those%20central%20points%20to%20which%20you%20can%20map%20textures%22&f=false) from *Real-Time 3D Rendering with DirectX and HLSL by Paul Varcholik*:

> In the geometry shader, you can create quads around those central points, to which you can map textures. Such objects are commonly known as point sprites.

What are point sprites? How do they work in a particle system?

Comment: A texture mapped point primitive, basically. We take for granted that points can be texture mapped these days, but that was not always the case and when this feature was introduced they were called point sprites.

Answer (score 4):

As the book says, a geometry shader can create new geometry in the pipeline. In this case, quads - which are just four vertices, or triangle pairs, that make up a 3D square. We often use quads to render [sprites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29), which are just images with a position either in 2D or 3D coordinates. In fact, most 2D game engines are actually rendering everything with three dimensions, but using quads facing an [orthographic camera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection).

Put another way, since every particle in a system is more or less identical, we just need to feed our image, its size in the world, and all the particle's positions into the shader effect, and it can tell the hardware to come up with all the little billboards with the image properly mapped onto each one.

Comment: What does he mean by"central points"? Central points mean one vertex or 4 vertices?

Comment: Central points meaning "where the particle is" - the four vertices of each quad are defined as points which are a fixed distance from the center point, so the particle's  position becomes the center.

Comment: particle is equivalent to 4 vertices?

Comment: Each particle instance is rendered using 4 vertices. The central point is just a position, a vector, not a vertex. The central point is an input, the four vertices are the output, for each particle.

Comment: central position is vector which is input and 4 vertices (quads) are output?and the textures that we can map onto quads must be quad or they  can be circle or rectangle ?

Comment: This is no such thing as a quad or circle texture - all textures are sections of rectangular images applied to geometry. I think you might need to start with something more basic, like "what makes up a vertex."